Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User') in NextJs
Hi Developers hope you will fine and doing well.
I was working on a simple website called Techryzer that is simple web development company website where i was practicing to create website with NextJs.
From Yesterday i am getting error from NextJs

This error is not displaying when i visit other routes but when I visit http://localhost:3000/dashboard/user/projects/new route. I am using Usermodel.js in that folder nor any APIs related to user model. I have tried to get help from ChatGPT, Gemini & Meta AI but failed to solve this error.
Here is complete code on github: https://github.com/sarfarazunarr/techryzer
Snippet of Prform.js (Component used on projects/new)
"use client";
import { getUserSession } from '../../../../../lib/utils';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { connectDB } from '../../../../../lib/db_connection';

function Prform() {
    const [pending, setPending] = useState(false);
    const [userid, setUserid] = useState();
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [data, setData] = useState({
      title: '',
      category: '',
      description: '',
      clientName: getUserSession()?.name || '',
      budget: 0,
      deadline: '',
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
        await connectDB();
          const sessiondata = await getUserSession();
          setUserid(sessiondata?.id || '');
          setData({
            title: '',
            category: '',
            description: '',
            clientName: sessiondata?.name || '',
            budget: 0,
            deadline: '',
          });
        };
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        setPending(true)
        try {
            console.log(data, userid)
            setMessage('Data Recieved')
            setPending(false)
            
        } catch (error) {
            setPending(false)
            setMessage('Error')
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    return (...

usermodel.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  phone: { type: String, required: true },
  registration_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  account_type: { type: String, enum: ['client', 'partner', 'admin'], default: 'client' },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

// Middleware to hash the password before saving
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

// Method to validate password
userSchema.methods.validatePassword = async function(password) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

export default User;


dbConnection.js and utils
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const connectString = process.env.MONGOURI
export async function connectDB() {
  if (mongoose.connections[0].readyState) return;

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(connectString);
    console.log("MongoDB connected successfully!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error);
  }

  return true;
}

//utils
const { authOptions } = require("../app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route");
const { getServerSession } = require("next-auth");
const base = process.env.BASE_URL;

export const getUserSession = async () => {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
    const sessionJSON = JSON.stringify(session, null, 2);
    const sessionData = JSON.parse(sessionJSON);
    const type = sessionData.user.account_type;
    const name = sessionData.user.name;
    const email = sessionData.user.email;
    const id = sessionData.user.id;
    const data = {name, email, id, type};
    return data;
}

export async function fetchApiData(path) {
    const base = process.env.BASE_URL
    const res = await fetch(base + path)
    const data = await res.json()
    return data;
  }


Please help me!
I have checked all routes and changed my prform.js which async before to non-async component and imported all hooks, functions, updated nextjs version from 14.2.3 to 14.2.4.

The error is telling you that on mongoose.models.User the object mongoose.models is undefined / not set.

But that same model is working in all other parts of application like login user, fetching userdata. In next js it is mandatory to add check-in in mongoose model to avoid OverWriting Mongoose model error from nextjs.
